# Opencart URL is changed

Tags: opencart

I have upgrade opencart to latest version. and the theme to latest version. After that i an not able to access the page with .html link

> www.test.com/product.html

instead of this its work like

> www.test.com/product

Can any one tell me how to slove this problem I am new to open cart and need help as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem will be that the extension you had to add the .html to URL's isn't working with your version. This isn't standard on OpenCart and the reason it's not working

Comment: Thanks you Jay Gilford,